# How to get metadata from online radio streaming in flutter

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I have a mixlr radio steaming url [Mixlr Url](https://edge.mixlr.com/channel/nmtev). I can play the url with just_audio but I need to show metadata info. For example, their radio is playing 24 mp3 files for each hour. They enter the title and artist name on mixlr server.

In flutter I need to show title and artist for each song. They show the example that can achieved on native iOS. We are migrating native iOS to flutter. Is it possible in flutter?

Comment: Have you tried the radio example from the plugin's GitHub repository?

Comment: @Ryan Heise, Currently I am using audio_service plugin for mp3 file. They also have one radio url. So I simply add the audio_service's mediaItem and playing. So that, I just tried to use just_audio alone for radio. Is there a way to get metadata in audio_service. I am using the audio_serice plugin's playlist and enhance it for other requirement.

Comment: I think the audio_service part is better as a separate question. I just wanted to be sure I understood your just_audio question before writing an answer. So does the radio example from the repo answer your just_audio question?

Comment: I've been experiencing a lengthy response time. I'm currently exploring the audio_service example, as opposed to just_audio. With just_audio, I can view the title, but there's no background service functionality. I'll continue to search for a solution.